# Transfer ownership Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I'm developing a connector between our platform and Docusign.
We need to create a Draft envelope in Docusign with a specific account and then transfer the ownership of the Draft to another account.

Looking at the documentation I've not found any clue of how we can do that, I just found how to create transfer rules but they don't fit our use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Envelope Transfer Rules can either happen at the point of sending, or the point of completion. While it's still a draft, an envelope cannot be transferred.

Additionally, Envelope Transfer is not currently available through the REST API, so all-or-nothing transfer rules are effectively the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Envelope Custody Transfer is only currently available for accounts that are part of the same Organization and on the same server. You can see which server your account is located on by going to Settings > Apps & Keys and checking the value for your account's baseUrl. For example, if both accounts have a baseUrl of [www.docusign.net](http://www.docusign.net), they can transfer between each other. If one is on [www.docusign.net](http://www.docusign.net), and the other is on na2.docusign.net, you cannot transfer the envelope.

Please see the following for additional details: https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/org-admin-guide-envelope-transfer